# How can I push to all the github origins with a git push?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

I have two origins in my git repo:

- Origin: this is the GitHub origin.
- Heroku: the Heroku origin.

How can I push to the master branch of both origins with a single `git push`? I'm currently doing `git push origin master && git push heroku master`, but I feel there's a easier way. Thanks!

Comment: `git push --all` pushes all your local branches to their respective origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<repo>/.git/config` you can do something like this (I'm assuming the `github` and `heroku` remotes are already defined, but you may have different actual names for them):

```
... other stuff ...
[remote "github"]
    fetch = <refspec>
    url = <github_url>
[remote "heroku"]
    fetch = <refspec>
    url = <heroku_url>
[remote "both"]
    url = <github_url>
    url = <heroku_url>
```

Then, when you run `git push both`, it will push to both. You can add fetch/push refspecs or other options to the "all" remote definition too, if appropriate/necessary. I don't think you can have different refspecs for the two urls, though so that could be a minor inconvenience...